# Read two sub nodes in single PHP XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using **PHP XPath** to read XML data. Can I read tow lines of address as below in single Xpath.

```
<Address>
<FirstLine>Indiabulls Finance Centre Tower</FirstLine>
<SecondLine>Elphinstone Road</SecondLine>
</Address>
```

Currently I am reading them as seperate XPath

```
 $xml->xpath('//Address/FirstLine');
 $xml->xpath('//Address/SecondLine');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use wildcard `"*"` to match any child of `Address`:

```
//Address/*
```

Also you can try

```
string-join(//Address/*, " ")
```

to get both values as single string `"Indiabulls Finance Centre Tower Elphinstone Road"`

Comment: I tried like   $xml->string-join("//cdt:Address/*", " "); but it shows error  join(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: No, I mean `$xml->xpath('string-join(//Address/*, " ")');`

Comment: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathCompOpEval: function string-concat not found

Comment: I think PHP XPath dont support string-concat

Comment: Maybe... And how about first option `$xml->xpath('//Address/*');`?

Comment: oh..I did not notice $xml->xpath('//Address/*'); first in answer. Yes it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath to fetch more then one node.

- combine two alternative location paths/expressions
  `/Address/FirstLine|/Address/SecondLine`
- fetch any Address child element node
  `/Address/*`
- fetch any Address child element node and filter them
  `/Address/*[self::FirstLine or self::SecondLine]`

Fetch the combined string directly is not possible with SimpleXML but in DOM. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` can only return arrays of nodes (represented by SimpleXMLElement objects). `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalars.

```
$xml = '<Address>
<FirstLine>Indiabulls Finance Centre Tower</FirstLine>
<SecondLine>Elphinstone Road</SecondLine>
</Address>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$result = $xpath->evaluate("concat(/Address/FirstLine, '\n', /Address/SecondLine)");

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(48) "Indiabulls Finance Centre Tower
Elphinstone Road"
```